# Admob causes corona SDK app to crash after installing GameAnalytics on Android

Tags: android, admob, coronasdk, gameanalytics

After "importing" the GameAnalytics plugin using (require "plugin.gameanalytics"), every time I try to launch a publicity via our Admob account (which worked perfectly until importing GameAnalytics), causes the app to crash, but only on Android, it does not give any error code or description, just closes the app with an 'error' popup and that's it.
Even if I don't include the require in my code, and remove any call gameanalytics, it still crashes the moment I call on Admob to display a publicity.
Can I "delete" the gameanalytics plugin somehow after the console first installed it? does anyone else had any problem with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to delete the plugin... just remove the GameAnalytics entry from the plugins table in your build.settings.

Does it still crash after doing that?

Could you post your GA setup and your build.settings here? 
then I will take a look at it.